# window onresize perform actions on breakpoints in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, breakpoints, window-resize

What I would like to do is create window breakpoints, like `300, 400, 500`
and perform a certain action when the window reaches a certain breakpoint, ideally could be something like:

```
300: function(){...}
400: function(){...}
500: function(){...}
```

and the following code is how I tried to **fire only 1 time** a certain function associated to a certain breakpoint, but actually I'm stuck because I don't know how to pass them dynamically inside a single little function, and because all breakpoints in my code look pretty the same and they are useless repeated...

```
breakpoints = [300, 400, 500];

function screenBreakpoints(){
    var regex = / ?breakpoint[0-9] ?/;
    if( $(window).width() < breakpoints[0] ){
        if( !$('html').hasClass('breakpoint0') ){
            $('html')[0].className = $('html')[0].className.replace(regex, '');
            $('html').addClass('breakpoint0');
            console.log('breakpoint0');
            $('li.MOVING').insertBefore('ul li.one'); // breakpoint function (fires only one time)
        }
    }
    else if( $(window).width() > breakpoints[0] && $(window).width() < breakpoints[1] ){
        if( !$('html').hasClass('breakpoint1') ){
            $('html')[0].className = $('html')[0].className.replace(regex, '');
            $('html').addClass('breakpoint1');
            console.log('breakpoint1');
            $('li.MOVING').insertBefore('ul li.two'); // breakpoint function (fires only one time)
        }
    }
    else if( $(window).width() > breakpoints[1] && $(window).width() < breakpoints[2] ){
        if( !$('html').hasClass('breakpoint2') ){
            $('html')[0].className = $('html')[0].className.replace(regex, '');
            $('html').addClass('breakpoint2');
            console.log('breakpoint2');
            $('li.MOVING').insertBefore('ul li.three'); // breakpoint function (fires only one time)
        }
    }
    else if( $(window).width() > breakpoints[1] ){
        if( !$('html').hasClass('breakpoint3') ){
            $('html')[0].className = $('html')[0].className.replace(regex, '');
            $('html').addClass('breakpoint3');
            console.log('breakpoint3');
            $('li.MOVING').insertBefore('ul li.four'); // breakpoint function (fires only one time)
        }
    }
}

$(window).resize(function(){
    screenBreakpoints();
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6vn1zk2f/)**

Comment: Do you mean that you just want a single function, which does all the job for you?

Comment: checkout the answer, you can use three different variables to keep track of the breakpoints and pass the function accordingly

Answer (score 0):

First you get the window `width` using jquery's [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) function.

Then declare three variables accordingly for the three sizes and write your functions inside that variable according to the condition

Keep the other two variables `empty` based on the `width` size and call the `screenBreakpoints`

> **NOTE:** As  @flowtron said in the comments, you can use `<=` or `>=` in the `if` condition based on your requirements

```
$(window).resize(function(){
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
if(viewportWidth == 300){ // Use <= or >= based on ur requirements
    var   function300= function300(){};
    var function400 ='';
    var function500='';
    screenBreakpoints(function300,function400,function500);
}
else if(viewportWidth == 400){  // Use <= or >= based on ur requirements
    var   function400= function400(){};
    var function300 ='';
    var function500='';
    screenBreakpoints(function300,function400,function500);
}
else if(viewportWidth == 500){  // Use <= or >= based on ur requirements
    var   function500= function500(){
    var function300 ='';
    var function400='';
};
screenBreakpoints(function300,function400,function500);
}
});
```

Then in your `screenBreakpoints` function check which parameter is `empty`

**For Ex:**

```
function screenBreakpoints(function300,function400,function500){
       if( $(window).width() < breakpoints[0] ){
            if(function300 != null && function300 != undefined){
            if( !$('html').hasClass('breakpoint0') ){
                $('html')[0].className = $('html')[0].className.replace(regex, '');
                $('html').addClass('breakpoint0');
                console.log('breakpoint0');
                $('li.MOVING').insertBefore('ul li.one'); // breakpoint function (fires only one time)
            }
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: this code won't work as expected - you can't be sure to hit the exact width, you'll at least have to go with <=, instead of ==. Also there is https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ so that regex isn't required ;-)

Comment: yeah..thanx for notifying, may be <= or >= will work, but that depends on OP's requirement. I will mention it in my answer. Modified it .thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In my work I've come to use a set of DIVs (usually invisible, not via `display: none` though!) that have an ID of "ThisIsMediaQuery_Alpha", .. Beta, Gamma .. however you name them and as many as you need - then each breakpoint you're interested in just has to modify one of these from the default settings all got initially - I usually use a background-color (legacy from when they were created to FIX a MediaQuery-usage and were visible), but anything you like can work really. Then just call `whichMediaQueryIsThis()` on `$(window).resize()`, which iterates over the DIVs and finds out which one has the "marker value" (e.g. `cur.style.backgroundColor=="red"`). Then just use a `case` to switch out the appropriate values when calling your `manageMediaQuerySwitch(arg0,arg1,arg2)` function. HTH

The upside of this is, it also works with MediaQueries that aren't pixel-oriented! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete edit that is done to the js file from the jsfiddle
the you provided. Just copy paste this over there or, just run this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vn1zk2f/1/). I found it working. What I'm doing is, I'm just making a single function and calling it with different parameters.

Here is your modified js

```
breakpoints = [300, 400, 500];
function screenBreakpoints(breakpoint,listName){
    var regex = / ?breakpoint[0-9] ?/;
        if( !$('html').hasClass(breakpoint) ){
            $('html')[0].className = $('html')[0].className.replace(regex, '');
            $('html').addClass(breakpoint);
            console.log(breakpoint);
            $('li.MOVING').insertBefore(listName); // breakpoint function (fires only one time)
        }
}    
$(window).resize(function(){
    if( $(window).width() < breakpoints[0] ){
        screenBreakpoints("breakpoint0","ul li.one");
    }
    else if( $(window).width() < breakpoints[1] ){
        screenBreakpoints("breakpoint1","ul li.two");        
    }
    else if( $(window).width() < breakpoints[2] ){
        screenBreakpoints("breakpoint2","ul li.three");        
    }
    else{
        screenBreakpoints("breakpoint3","ul li.four");
    }
});
```